# Storage Spaces BSOD after re-installing Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, bsod, storage-spaces

After reinstalling Windows 8.1, reconnecting my Storage Spaces array causes a BSOD.

I have a 3 drive Storage Spaces array + separate SSD.  I re-installed Windows 8 -> and upgrade to 8.1

After installing Windows 8 after the first reboot my machine went into a reboot loop with a BSOD.  After removing all of the drives, the machine comes up normally.

If I only connect a single drive, no crash.  I've tried putting the drives onto separate controllers (I have Intel and ASMedia SATA [controllers](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z77V_PRO/#specifications)), and as soon as I add a second drive, the BSOD returns (shortly after it initializes the drive).

**Am I completely hosed or is there some way to recover the array?**

### Driver Versions

Intel: 12.9.0.1001 - 10/29/2013
ASR: 1.3.4.0 - 6/22/2012
spaceport.sys: 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623) - 10/30/2013 6:38:47 PM?

### Error

```
Error: DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL  
file path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\spaceport.sys
```

Minidump: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yqtnjxvvdvq2nqq/032914-5109-01.dmp

### Windows Action Center error

```
Source
Windows

Summary
Shut down unexpectedly

Date
‎3/‎29/‎2014 7:29 PM

Status
Solution available  (note, the solution isn't actually available)

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
Code:   d1
Parameter 1:    ffffe0001de00ffe
Parameter 2:    2
Parameter 3:    1
Parameter 4:    fffff8000021dc90
OS version: 6_3_9600
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    256_1
OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  AV_spaceport!LogDecodeEntryHeader
```

### WinDgb (analyze -v)

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffe0001de00ffe, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000001, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff80000597c90, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


WRITE_ADDRESS:  ffffe0001de00ffe 

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
spaceport!LogDecodeEntryHeader+58
fffff800`00597c90 42884411fe      mov     byte ptr [rcx+r10-2],al

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  AV

PROCESS_NAME:  System

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) amd64fre

TRAP_FRAME:  ffffd00021fa6610 -- (.trap 0xffffd00021fa6610)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000020000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=00000000179e6000
rdx=00000000179e5000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80000597c90 rsp=ffffd00021fa67a8 rbp=ffffe0000641b000
 r8=00000000000179e5  r9=0000000000000000 r10=ffffe0000641b000
r11=ffffe0000641b000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
spaceport!LogDecodeEntryHeader+0x58:
fffff800`00597c90 42884411fe      mov     byte ptr [rcx+r10-2],al ds:ffffe000`1de00ffe=??
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff803ee75b7e9 to fffff803ee74fca0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`21fa64c8 fffff803`ee75b7e9 : 00000000`0000000a ffffe000`1de00ffe 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000001 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd000`21fa64d0 fffff803`ee75a03a : 00000000`00000001 00000000`000179e6 ffffe000`06ba5000 ffffd000`21fa6610 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
ffffd000`21fa6610 fffff800`00597c90 : fffff800`00597db2 ffffe000`080a1970 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000060 : nt!KiPageFault+0x23a
ffffd000`21fa67a8 fffff800`00597db2 : ffffe000`080a1970 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000060 ffffe000`06ba5000 : spaceport!LogDecodeEntryHeader+0x58
ffffd000`21fa67b0 fffff800`0059ad00 : ffffe000`080a1970 00000000`000e4000 00000000`00000000 ffffe000`06ba5000 : spaceport!LogReadRecordComplete+0x3e
ffffd000`21fa67f0 fffff800`0059933f : 00000000`00001000 ffffe000`080a7d80 0003b497`000000e4 00000000`00000000 : spaceport!LogCoreReadDataRecord+0x1d8
ffffd000`21fa6860 fffff800`0058f3f5 : ffffe000`080a7d80 ffffe000`0807b910 0003b497`000000e4 00000000`00000006 : spaceport!SlLogReadLogRecord+0x1a7
ffffd000`21fa68e0 fffff800`00587032 : ffffe000`080a7d80 ffffe000`00000000 ffffe000`07457c18 00000000`00000000 : spaceport!SIO_LOG::BuildChildPacketsRead+0x115
ffffd000`21fa6950 fffff800`00586e94 : ffffe000`080a7d80 ffffe000`07457c18 00000000`00000000 ffffe000`0807b910 : spaceport!SIO_DISPATCH::DispatchInternal+0x32
ffffd000`21fa6990 fffff800`0058adca : ffffe000`080a7d80 ffffe000`07457c0d 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : spaceport!SIO_DISPATCH::Dispatch+0x5c
ffffd000`21fa69c0 fffff800`0058707b : ffffe000`080a7bf8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : spaceport!SIO_RAID::DispatchChildPacket+0xd6
ffffd000`21fa69f0 fffff800`00586e94 : ffffe000`0807bc00 ffffe000`07457c0d 00000000`00000000 ffffe000`07449a00 : spaceport!SIO_DISPATCH::DispatchInternal+0x7b
ffffd000`21fa6a30 fffff800`005889f3 : ffffe000`0807bc78 ffffe000`07457cc0 ffffe000`0807bed0 00000000`00000001 : spaceport!SIO_DISPATCH::Dispatch+0x5c
ffffd000`21fa6a60 fffff800`0058830a : ffffe000`0807bf28 ffffd000`21fa6ae0 ffffe000`039f2650 ffffe000`0807bed0 : spaceport!SIO_DESTAGE::RefillReplay+0x17f
ffffd000`21fa6aa0 fffff800`0058730e : fffff800`005872d8 ffffe000`039f2650 ffffe000`039f2650 ffffe000`05883880 : spaceport!SIO_DESTAGE::Run+0x2b2
ffffd000`21fa6b10 fffff803`ee6a31b9 : fffff800`005872d8 ffffd000`21fa6bd0 ffffe000`039f2650 ffffe000`0669e820 : spaceport!SioTaskWorkerRoutine+0x36
ffffd000`21fa6b50 fffff803`ee68f2e4 : ffffd000`207e8340 ffffe000`05883880 ffffe000`05883880 ffffe000`003b2900 : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x2b5
ffffd000`21fa6c00 fffff803`ee7562c6 : ffffd000`207dc180 ffffe000`05883880 ffffd000`207e8340 bbb643fc`01d4ab98 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x58
ffffd000`21fa6c60 00000000`00000000 : ffffd000`21fa7000 ffffd000`21fa1000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
spaceport!LogDecodeEntryHeader+58
fffff800`00597c90 42884411fe      mov     byte ptr [rcx+r10-2],al

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  spaceport!LogDecodeEntryHeader+58

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: spaceport

IMAGE_NAME:  spaceport.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  52718a77

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.3.9600.16452

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  58

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_spaceport!LogDecodeEntryHeader

BUCKET_ID:  AV_spaceport!LogDecodeEntryHeader

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:av_spaceport!logdecodeentryheader

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {1ed79302-c2e8-c1d4-cadf-6637f8d3ad77}

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Comment: +1 for actually researching and providing all the required information! I wish I could help though

Comment: Thanks! its a confusing (frustrating/scary) one - I've cross posted here as well - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-system/getting-an-error-driverirqlnotlessorequal-while/9219cb60-5293-4818-910d-2b982c6e54e2

Comment: Update - i have an open case with MSFT support, i've attached the drives to a virtualbox VM with the same problem. looks like a true bug in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get a bugfix from Microsoft but recovered the files with the following steps:

- Using Powershell, set the VirtualDisk to not automount: `Set-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName "BadDisk" -IsManualAttach $True`
- Physically reattach all drives (the BSOD is when initializing the VirtualDisk)
- Download and use [Reclaime File Recovery](http://www.reclaime.com/) and use the demo of [Storage Spaces Recovery](http://www.storage-spaces-recovery.com/) (note, I only had to pay for Relclaime in order to recover files).

On a separate drive, copy all of the files from the bad VirtualDisk, and then delete it.